# svn permissions do not work according to their configuration

Tags: svn

I'm working with svn repository and i'm trying to change its permissions so that one user will be able to r/w and the only to r/ only.

I'd liek user approved to have r/w and user unapproved to have r permissions only. 
my configuration is as follow:

### passwd

```
[users]    

approved = approved    
unapproved = unapproved
```

### authz

```
[/MyRepository]

approved = rw    
* = r
```

But for some reason the user 'approved' get the following error when trying to commit:
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Authorization failed

i'd appropriate any guidance on this subject. by reading the svn docs i was sure i'm doing the proper configuration but still, it does not work.

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `svn://` or `http://` server?

Answer (score 0):

First off, how are you doing your Subversion repository. You can use Apache httpd, or the `svnserve` command.

If you're using `svnserve`, you probably want something like this:

#### $REPOROOT/conf/svnserve.conf

```
...
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
...
password-db = passwd
...
authz-db = authz
```

#### authz file

```
[groups]

[/]
* = r
bob = rw
```

#### passwd file

```
[users]
bob = swordfish
carol = pike
ted = redsnapper
alice = groupper
```

Note that I put `[/]` to indicate the root of my repository. Putting `[/MyRepository]` gives the users access only under that directory in the repository.

The above will prevent anonymous access, and only bob will have the ability to commit any changes. The other users, carol, ted, and alice can read from the repository.

If you want anonymous access, things are even easier. Get rid of the authz file entirely, and only put bob in your passwd file. In your `svnserver.conf` file, set things this way:

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
...
password-db = passwd
...
#  authz-db = authz   Don't want this file active
```

If you are using Apache httpd to access your repository, things will be a bit more complex. You need to setup the httpd.conf file (or a file it reads in) to do your setup. You can use the built in `htpasswd` file and command that encrypts your passwords in the file, or you can use LDAP (you can use LDAP in `svnserve` too, but it's even more complex to setup.)

Comment: hi David, thanks for the answer. 
I'm using svnserve. i did exactly as you suggested but when i try to commit something as bob, i get the following: 

bob@P$ svn commit -m "test" postbuild
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Authorization failed

any ideas?

Comment: Let's take things one step at a time. Try `svn commit --username bob`, or whatever user is a valid user. Get rid of that authz database for now. Allow all users to do the commit. See if the problem is the password database (You did remove that beginning "#" from the `password-db` in `svnserve.conf` file?). If that works, then you can add the `authz` back in and see if you can solve the problems there. One step at a time.